# How to connect to local runtime in Google Colab for this specific notebook WhisperWithVAD

Tags: google-colaboratory, text-to-speech, openai-whisper

I wish someone could help me to connect local runtime on this specific notebook on Google Colab at this link:
`https://colab.research.google.com/github/ANonEntity/WhisperWithVAD/blob/main/WhisperWithVAD.ipynb`
Basically it is a modified version of OpenAI's Whisper for Speech-to-Text for my videos to learn languages, with this model it take use of GPU accellation acceleration
I have been using the free version but it has been restricted due to the fact that it is not unlimited to use this model through Google's host. Since I am not really a dev, I have difficulties with the setup. It would be also if you can give me a clear instruction.

[Corresponding with error in Colab: Unable to connect to runtime](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xGzy8.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow these instructions to install Jupyter on your local machine and then connect the WhisperWithVAD notebook to your local runtime: https://research.google.com/colaboratory/local-runtimes.html

I was able to get this up running, but had to comment out some code in the Run Whisper block where the notebook was getting hung up:

`#from google.colab import files` (near the top of the block)
and
`#files.download(out_path)` (at the bottom of the block)